# Jinja2: use template to build a string variable

Tags: jinja2

Jinja2 supports [very useful filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#filters) to modify a string, eg.

```
{{ my_string|capitalize }}
```

What about you want to build the input string? When the string is simple you can always use

```
{% set my_string = string_1 + string_2 %}
{{ my_string|capitalize }}
```

But it would be wonderful to actually build this string **using templates**, just like

```
{% set my_string = "{{ 'a' }}b{{ 'c' }}" %}
{{ my_string|capitalize }}
```

that would output `Abc`..
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer exists in Jinja 2.8, as documented [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#block-assignments)

The answer is

```
{% set my_string %}
  {{ 'a'}}b{{ 'c' }}
{% endset %}
```